# When I make a reference to a global variable, why does the closure not reflect a change to the original?

Tags: javascript

In an app I'm developing, I define a global `App` namespace, where I store some properties that I want to access from different functions. For example I might keep a menu `menuOpen` property stored in my global `App` namespace so the function that I use to handle the Menu interface functionality can share this information easily with a different function that handles something else.

I was having a problem with this a moment ago, after updating this global variable with one function, and then checking a *reference* to it in the closure of another function, to find the reference didn't reflect my change.

I re-recreated this in a simple example, where I would expect `false` to be the result, since `bar` changes `open` to `false`, which should be reflected by `state` within `foo`'s closure before the timeout completes and runs the check against `state`:

```js
//set a global variable to be accessed by different parts 
//of an application
var open = true;

//create a closure, which waits for a future event, 
//then checks the "open" variable when it occurs
function foo() {

  //reference to the global variable "open"
  var state = open;

  //set a timeout, to reflect "a future event", such 
  //as an event handler
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (state) {
      $('html').text('true');
    } else {
      $('html').text('false');
    }
  }, 1000);
}

//change the "open" global within another function
function bar() {
  open = false;
}

//create the closure
foo();

//change "open" to false, before the "if(state)" logic 
//is called in the closure
bar();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It was my understanding that a closure keeps a reference to a variable, so `state` would reflect any change to `open`. How does this actually work? And what would I need to do differently to make `foo`'s closure aware of `open`'s change?

Comment: objects will self-update like described but primitives are copied on assignment. you can see `open` from inside the closure, and that should reflect the same value as the outside variable.

Comment: `// reference to the global variable "open"`. Nope. In an assignment expression, the value is copied. You reference variables by name, not reference.

Comment: @RobG yeah, in the comments to an answer below they explained it. That's really the answer to my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, this issue doesn't have anything to do with closures.  It has to do with how Javascript does assignment of different types.

Only objects in Javascript are assigned by pointer.  All other data types are assigned by value (e.g. the value is copied).  So, when you do:

```
var state = open;
```

And, `open` is anything other than an object (which includes objects, arrays and functions), then the value in `open` is copied to `state` and the two variables then have nothing to do with one another.

See this example:

```js
var myNum = 12;
var otherNum = myNum;
document.write("myNum = ", myNum, "<br>");          // 99
document.write("otherNum = ", otherNum, "<br>");    // 12

myNum = 99;
document.write("myNum = ", myNum, "<br>");          // 99
document.write("otherNum = ", otherNum, "<br>");    // still 12
```

But, if you assigned an object, it would just be a pointer to the original object so if the original was changed, you would see that change in the other reference to that same object:

```js
function log(name, obj) {
    document.write(JSON.stringify(obj) + "<br>");
}

var myObj = {greeting: "hello"};
var otherObj = myObj;
log("myObj", myObj);
log("otherObj", otherObj);

myObj.greeting = "bye";
log("myObj", myObj);
log("otherObj", otherObj);
```

Objects are assigned by pointer to the original.  All other types of variables behave as if they are copied and no longer have a connection to the original.

If you want to take a normal non-object variable and get it to behave like you have a pointer to it, then you can put that variable into an object as a property on that object and you can pass the object around.  Then, everyone who you pass the object to can examine the property and they will all be looking at exactly the same property value.  If one changes it, they will all see the changed value.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with closures. `var x = "a"; var y = x; x = "b"; console.log(y)` outputs `"a"`, not `"b"`, because `y` is a copy of `x`.

Closures don't change the normal behavior of variables. A closure is simply a function that uses local variables from a surrounding scope. `foo` is a closure because it uses `open`; the function passed to `setTimeout` is a closure because it uses `state` (but `state` never changes after being set).

You can fix your code by checking `if (open)` directly.

Comment: So, lets say my Global `App` namespace has a large structure - Since you say making a reference `var state = open` doesn't reflect changes to `open`, is there any way to use a shortcut for a long global variable name within a  function? I see that I could fix my problem (I think) by just referencing `open` directly, but what if `open` were located at `App.Modules.Menu.open` and I use that variable 10 times in my function - is there no way to shorten it within the function like I'm trying to do with the `state` variable?

Comment: @JonathanTodd It depends on how the variable is changed. If It's something like `App.Modules.Menu.state = 42`, then it suffices to keep `var menu = App.Modules.Menu` around (and check `menu.state`). But that won't work if someone does `App.Modules.Menu = { "state": "surprise!" }`, thereby completely redefining one of the higher layers.

Comment: Oh... That's weird. Know of any article / blog on that you could link that explains that behavior? Even just knowing what that topic is called (beyond 'variable scope') would suffice.

Comment: @JonathanTodd: look into pass by reference vs pass by value for js

Comment: So the answer to this question is really that I'm *not* making a reference.

Comment: @JonathanTodd It's a consequence of how "object values" are actually references to the underlying objects, so `var menu = App.Modules.Menu` only copies the reference, not the actual object. That's why `menu` observes changes made to the object (no matter which reference they're made through). On the other hand, `App.Modules.Menu = { ... }` creates a completely new object.

Comment: Not exactly nothing to do with closures, the fix is to use the closure to *open*, not the value copied to *state* (though such closures to global variables are trivial and not really worth calling closures).